# Why can I suddenly not access my command line history?

Tags: ksh, command-history

I use `ksh` (version: sh (AT&T Research) 2020.0.0) on Ubuntu 20.04, and I use vi command line editing mode (`set -o vi`). This has worked fine for years, but recently I have noticed some oddities, and finally this morning it stopped working altogether.

- I can see commands are no longer being saved in `~/.sh_histfile` as of this morning
- In the past, all commands I entered could be found by scrolling up with <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> or eg. searching with <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>.
- A while ago, this seemed to change to only remembering successful commands (which is a nuisance).

I haven't made any changes to my configuration yesterday (I think), but command line history works for the root user.

Permissions on `~/.sh_histfile` are 600, and `HISTFILE` is not set, either for my normal user or root.

Any idea what has gone wrong - and of course how to fix it? Ideally I want to get back to the situation when anything I wrote on the command line and finished with <kbd>Enter</kbd> would be saved to `~/.sh_histfile`.

***Edit***

The following variables are set:

```
$ set
_=export
COMP_CWORD=0
COMP_KEY=0
COMP_POINT=0
COMP_TYPE=0
COMP_WORDBREAKS=$'"\'@><=;|&(:'
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS='unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
DISPLAY=localhost:11.0
ENV=/home/jan.andersen/.kshrc
FCEDIT=/usr/bin/ex
HISTCMD=1
HOME=/home/jan.andersen
IFS=$' \t\n'
JOBMAX=0
KSH_VERSION=.sh.version
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LESS=X
LINENO=1
LOGNAME=jan.andersen
MAILCHECK=600
MOTD_SHOWN=pam
OLDPWD=/home/jan.andersen
OPTIND=1
PATH=/home/jan.andersen/.local/bin:/usr/local/glassfish5/bin:/usr/local/glassfish5/glassfish/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
PPID=3887
PS1=$'\'$ \''
PS2='> '
PS3='#? '
PS4='+ '
PWD=/home/jan.andersen
RANDOM=18082
SECONDS=17131.589
SHELL=/usr/bin/ksh
SHLVL=1
SH_OPTIONS=astbin=/opt/ast/bin
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
TERM=xterm-256color
TMOUT=0
USER=jan.andersen
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
XDG_SESSION_ID=10
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
```

The local profile contains only default stuff and a coule of lines at the end, that I've added:

```
$ cat .profile
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi

#eval $(ssh-agent -s)
#ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/ssh-agent.socket
```

Comment: What's the `HISTSIZE` variable set to?

Comment: Any clues in environment? Typically do `export` or `env` from shell.

Comment: The output of `env` is not really helpful as variables affecting the shell's behaviour do not need to have been exported as environment variables. Consider updating your question with your `~/.profile` file and possibly any other file that you may be sourcing at shell startup (e.g. the file that the `$ENV` value mentions, if any).

Comment: You have `ENV=/home/jan.andersen/.kshrc`.  Could you please show the contents of `/home/jan.andersen/.kshrc`?

Comment: @Kusalananda It doesn't exist

Comment: Have you tried to move / remove the history file? IIRC I read something about that it should exist on start (due to some bug), so better `touch` it to create a empty one as in `mv .sh_histfile .sh_hisftile.bak`  `touch .sh_histfile`

Comment: @ibuprofen Or just remove the file and the shell _should_ create it with the next interactive shell session (my `ksh` (`sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01`) does that). Hmm... that makes me wonder, try installing the `ksh93` package instead of the `ksh` package. The `ksh` package on Ubuntu seems to contain an unofficial release.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Yes. Op uses v 2020.0.0. There are issues with history. https://github.com/att/ast/issues/1271 , https://github.com/att/ast/issues/1432 (https://github.com/att/ast/issues/1432#issuecomment-550124519) etc.

Comment: It is (strange?) it does not report any errors though in OP's case.

Comment: @ibuprofen Note that those issues were opened against the `ksh` project before it was decided to roll back _several years of development_ to the `ksh93u+` release (with `ksh93v-` as an unstable release).  The `ksh 2020` release was rolled back and for all accounts and purposes forgotten. There was drama, strong words, and hurt feeling involved, if I remember correctly (I was watching the messages at the time).  I would suggest that the OP move to `ksh93`, which is better understood and more mature.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Yes - as OP has the 2020.0.0 version I thought it prudent to mention. And, yes, a "rollback" for OP would very likely be the best. Not sure why Ubuntu decided not to do `ksh`=ksh93 + `ksh2020` or `ksh93` + `ksh2020` … or something there around. I'm rather uninformed about the 93/2020 debacle but have the gist of it I think. Would fun to find out why it is happening, but that's the curious ego in me lol.

Comment: Added an update to answer. From what I can see you would likely be best in installing the `93` version.

Comment: @ibuprofen It seems your suggestion of removing `.sh_histfile` solved the problem. I can't quite imagine why, but there you are. If you will write this up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n: Sure, I can update answer further if it is unclear? (Did you read last update?). Checked out and unfortunately it looks like there is no package for ksh93 on Ubuntu 20. You *can* build from source. Else, hopefully, they do a "stable release update" after a while where they add the 93 version. Honestly the more I look into it the more provoked I get about the pack lol.

Comment: @ibuprofen Sorry, of course! I've accepted your answer now.

Comment: Most important for me is that it 1. solved as far as possible, and 2. clear. It often find it  hard to see clarity of my own writings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *not verified* by other sources, but merely a look at the case.

NB! This relates to ksh-2020.

There is a bug in the handling of history when history gets above a certain size (bytes). It manifests itself in that history length is 1 (aka zero) and stays there. If one reach the limit that triggers the bug while in `ksh` it manifest itself on next run.

Using something like:

```
PS1='$_pwd [!]\$ '
```

shows path + number of history entries.

In a normal run [`sh_histinit`](https://github.com/att/ast/blob/42e726f8d004ec2220a291f5a54f000a0c471762/src/cmd/ksh93/edit/history.c#L112) is called on start. For some reason, not tracked down, this function is called *for every command* when this bug is active. Further [`hist_write`](https://github.com/att/ast/blob/42e726f8d004ec2220a291f5a54f000a0c471762/src/cmd/ksh93/edit/history.c#L559) is normally called, to write the record, but this is not called when bug is active.

As a result one end up with ***a new file descriptor*** to `.sh_hisory` for ***every command***. This is likely what you also saw in `/proc/PID/fd` as noted in comments. Further commands are not written to file.

Solution, at least here, is to archive the old history and start a new. Likely advisable to restart shell.

Without `HISTSIZE` defined, the limit for triggering the bug is small. A few hundred records. You can set it to a big number, like 50000, to "delay" it. In my tests it was then triggered around 32k lines with a size of 50000. Increased size to 500000 and then it worked as expected again.

As noted it is also likely advisable to install `ksh93` instead of the 2020 version. From the looks of things the 2020 has stalled. (`93` does not mean it is from 1993 - but based on that version. Likely `93u`)

The `93u` version does not have this bug.

If `/etc/skel/.kshrc` is not sourced you likely also want to copy that file to your home directory. It *likely* already have a `HISTSIZE` set, change that to a big value if you continue with the 2020 release.

---

---

### Original "comment"

This is too long for a comment, so I write it as an "answer". (Assuming Linux)

You could possibly find a clue to what is going on by:

---

In one terminal run `ksh` normally. Get the pid of that shell.

Check `/proc/PID/fd/`. It should typically have open fd 3 to `/home/username/.sh_history`

In second shell do `strace -p PID`. In first shell when you enter `k` you should typically see something like this in the shell running `strace`.

### Read history by `k`:

```
select(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL)        = 1 (in [0])
recvfrom(0, 0x7ffdcff6c0d0, 80, MSG_PEEK, NULL, NULL) = -1 ENOTSOCK (Socket operation on non-socket)
read(0, "k", 80)                        = 1
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(3, "\201\1[ --help\n\0exit\n\0env\n\0\0ls\n\0q\n\0\0"..., 65536) = 258
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_END)                   = 258
write(2, "man foo\10\10\10\10\10\10\10", 14) = 14
```

Here:

`read(0, "k", 80) = 1` *read from STDIN*, read 1 byte, "k" (The key entered)
`read(3, "\201\1[ ...` *read 65536 bytes from fd 3*, read history file.
`write(2, "man foo...` *write `man foo`*, the previous command is shown.

### Write history:

In the first shell enter a command. In log below I entered `cd irc` from `~/tmp`

Excerpt from *entering `c<Enter>`*

```
write(2, "c", 1)                        = 1
select(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL)        = 1 (in [0])
recvfrom(0, 0x7ffdcff6c0d0, 80, MSG_PEEK, NULL, NULL) = -1 ENOTSOCK (Socket operation on non-socket)
read(0, "\r", 80)                       = 1
ioctl(2, TCGETS, {B38400 opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(2, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(2, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_END)                   = 270
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 270
lseek(3, 270, SEEK_SET)                 = 270
read(3, "", 65536)                      = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_END)                   = 270
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_END)                   = 270
write(3, "cd irc\n\0", 8)               = 8
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 278
chdir("irc")                            = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_END)                   = 278
lseek(3, 278, SEEK_SET)                 = 278
lseek(3, 278, SEEK_SET)                 = 278
read(3, "", 65536)                      = 0
write(2, "~/tmp/irc [36]$ ", 16)        = 16
```

Here the:
`write(3, "cd irc\n\0", 8)               = 8`

is the line that writes to the history file.

Comment: We must assume that the user is not lying, so stracing the process should not show writing to or reading from `~/.sh_history`.  Your answer lacks a way of diagnosing anything or saying  anything other than "that's not what happens".

Comment: @Kusalananda: Absolutely. But curious as to if it could yield some *hint* on what is happening. Does it for example for some unknown reason write to another file somewhere else ... - "luckily" the strace of a shell in this manner is not very verbose (not much noise).

Comment: @Kusalananda I find the answer very useful. The list of open files in /proc/PID/fd is strange - there are 7 descriptors pointing to my history file, starting from 11 to 17, and in the trace I see the shell access fd=3 (and succeeds!), but apparently it isn't attached to a file (?)

Comment: @j4nd3r53n: That sounds strange. At the same time I have `SHELL=/bin/bash` so not the best test environment. If no-one enters an answer I can have a look at a VM later ...

Comment: @ibuprofen Yes, it is odd - the only difference from root's environment is that it has only one file descriptor poiting to .sh_history

Comment: @j4nd3r53n: Compiled and ran same version as yours. Not able to reproduce. Also tried to fill up history file with loads of data, but still no problems. There is a change from my previous trace in that it uses fd10 instead of 3. Running `strace -ty -o log.strace` and looking at that log, it opens 3, dupes it (gets fd 10), and closes 3. Extracted segments from log: https://termbin.com/to1i

Comment: @j4nd3r53n: Err. That should be `strace -ty -o log.strace ksh`